# Entity Framework 5 code-first configuration encapsulation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I was wondering (and I hate using the words 'Best Practice') - but is this a good way to approach configuration as it encapsulates the config for AAA?

I see a lot of examples where the `OnModelCreating` is a huge list of instructions for creating the database and long methods tell me something isn't quiet right.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name=MyDb") { }

    public DbSet<AAA> AAAs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AAA.Configuration());
    }
}
```

And the class with a spot for it's config

```
public class AAA
{
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public string Details { get; set; }

    internal class Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AAA>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            // Set all the funky stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

I get that there probably isn't ***one right way***. Before I commit a lot of time and tears I am looking for a reason why this might be absolutely the worst idea in the world or if there is a way to do something similar?

***EDIT***

A Colleague suggested this as an alternate method using a static property

```
public class AAA
{
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public static EntityTypeConfiguration<AAA> Configuration
    {
        get { return new AAAConfiguration(); }
    }

}

internal class AAAConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AAA>
{
   public AAAConfiguration()
   {
            // Set all the funky stuff here
   }
}
```

I like this as it gives me a bit more flexibility with how the configuration is instanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. I am by now far enough to say that I don't care about db generation. It is nice and has advantages (platform independent) which I do not care about. it is limiting from using SQL Server fully - so it is back to database projects.

This is a world of compromises, and - sorry- a best practice comes with a TON of limitations there.

Comment: Yeah I really think Dapper or a Similar DAL is a better choice. For all the noob magic, it just seems to be slow and clunky when you want volumes of data processed and you are alway limited by the constraints of the conventions.

Comment: not sure. I used BlToolkit so far for the terrific speed - in a project dealing with hundreds of millins of rows, I was macxing out a 96 core SSD backed ExaData Server with a 24 core Intel server - but now I am moving towards EntityFramework for a trading project. THAT SAID: I dont do db maintenance there, as I also have stored procedures, views, multiple filegroups and other features in the db that code first just does not know about. Code first in EF is still VERY limited.

Comment: Yeah I didn't really want to use it. It was foisted upon me. Now I have to learn it enough to be able to say no next time although I must admit it is very good for rapid development of an idea. trouble it its not very sustainable when the idea becomes the reality.

Comment: it REALLY depends. For most scenarios "define fields in tables and relationships and indices" may be enough. Things get different when you also need views, set up stored procedures, triggers, use tuning (filegroups) or start using enterprise features (table partitioning).

Comment: @Peter it can be pretty sustainable (especially with code first migrations -- lets your source control your entire DB history, which is awesome) -- way easier than maintaining a mountain of SQL scripts IMHO. -- Also a lot of the other stuff that people complain about (i.e. views, etc.) are on their feature road map... so it's coming.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't see an issue in the approach you have taken. I have just recently resolved a similar dilema in my head, the only difference being is I have the `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` classes inside my data layer and not within my model. I'm doing all the mapping logic in these mapping classes too; this means I don't have to decorate my model with EF specific attributes, keeping them totally persistence-ignorant.

With your approach, in the `OnModelCreating` method you only need to have one line per class that you want to persist, plus this code is only hit once if you don't clear the cache that EF creates, so it's only a kind of one-off bootstrap and therefore a long method isn't an issue?

I think your approach is fine, but I'm sure there will be some differing views on the subject.